# How to get assets files url in yii?

Tags: yii

I added CKEditor to my yii webApp and now i have problem with **filebrowserBrowseUrl** attribute,
What should i put instead of **4db59eda** folder? Or how can i get assets files and folders url?

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'Projects_content',
        {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl :'http://localhost/altin/assets/4db59eda/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Connector=http://localhost/altin/assets/4db59eda/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
```

Answer (score 0):

At my project I've included the files in a folder called "js" at app root. It's at the same level of protected, css and etc.

You can add your scripts to your page like the following example:

```
$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/yourscript.js');
```

The best way to use URL's at the Yii is with Yii::app()->baseUrl.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, files and folders are in hashed sub folder [like this **4db59eda**] in assets folder, I wanna know how can i get files and folders url?

Comment: Well, I don't know how to make this. For example, if you want to access a registered core script that is loaded to assets sub folder, like jquery, you use something like <?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>. But to your specific case, I don't know how to proceed...

Comment: Maybe this forum topic could help you: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12009-how-to-register-jquery-ui-css-file-in-yii-114/